# Veeam Backup: Failed to Freeze Guest

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi

Should I be concerned about this error in Veeam:

```
Freezing guest operating system
VSSControl: Failed to freeze guest, wait timeout
```

It seems to be proceeding with the backups. What does this error mean?

Comment: You are aware of Google? [A simple search](http://www.google.de/search?q=failed+to+freeze+guest+wait+timeout) would have come up with a number of helpful-looking hits, have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdamF, It appears that you may be attempting to backup the vCenter SQL Server, this is a common error that occurs because the VSS operation can freeze SQL because vCenter has control of it. There are work-arounds, I recommend you take a look at the Veeam forums and search for this specific VSS error. http://forums.veeam.com